# how to display confirm message in modal bootstrap from post action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

in my MVC 4 Application i want submit my forms to server, so that,when a user click on submit button a modal bootstrap confirmation is displayed if certain condition, if he click yes a form well be submited, else he retourned to form

but i don't knew how to return a confirmation message from controller post action to bootstrap modal

there is my controller post action methode

```
  if (uniteOfWorkBll.MoneyBLL.IsAnneeCloture(periode.Value, out message) )//condition of displaying confirmation bootstrap modal
        {
            TempData["WarningMessage"] = message;//confirmation message but is not
               // displayed in modal popup      

        }

        else
        {//normal submitting

            uniteOfWorkBll.MoneyBLL.AddMonnais(monnaies, typePeriode, periode, structureId, annee);

            //return View(monnaiesAct);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new {structureId = structureId, typePeriode=typePeriode, periode=periode, annee=annee });                         
        }

        ViewBag.StructureId = new SelectList(uniteOfWorkBll.StructureBLL.GetListStructures(User.Identity.Name), "StructureId", "Designation", structureId);
        ViewBag.Periode = Helpers.EnumHelper.GetEnumNames(typeEnumPeriode);
        ViewBag.TypePeriode = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(TypePeriode)));
        ViewBag.Annee = new SelectList(uniteOfWorkBll.DraBLL.GetAllAnnees(x => true), annee);
        ViewBag.TypeMoney = Helpers.EnumHelper.GetEnumNames(typeof(TypeMoney));
        return View("Index");
    }
```

any help?

Comment: I mean. Usually for modals of any sort, they are implemented into the code using a  javascript function and an ajax call to get the data for what you want in the modal.

Comment: As far as i can think is, you need to have 2 flags in model, showPopup and other flag isConfirmed. In the GetRequest both the values will be false. on the first submit. you will post showPopup as true and isConfirmed as false. When the view is rendered  you will use these flags to show the popup. When someone confirms as yes you will set the showPopup flag as false and isConfirmed as true. else you will set showPopup as true and isConfirmed as false when you returning the view. On the UI you can write script to use these values from model. I believe you can use viewbag as well.

Comment: if you add some snipped of view and your GET and POST method then it will be easy to post some pseudo code for you.